# Eror gson.JsonSyntaxException

Tags: android, json, gson

Estoy recogiendo de un webService un **JSON** y en teoría da un error al parsear un double, pero en mi **SELECT** no hay ningun campo que tenga tal tipo de dado.

***BBDD:***

Todos los campos son de tipo **VARCHAR** salvo `id` que es de tipo **INT** y `date` que es de tipo **DATETIME**, pero no le selecciono.

***PHP DEL WEB SERVICE***

```
if($bdd) {
    

// FETCH_ASSOC
$sql = "SELECT id, tipo, usuario, org, a, d, p, r, rI, rF, pP, pA, c, p1, p2, p3, p4, t1, t2, t3, t4, e1, e2, e3, e4, fI, fF, hI, hF, nD, dur, v, apar, info FROM p WHERE usuario = :usuario AND id = :id";

    if( $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql) ) 
    {
        $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
        $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
        $stmt -> execute(); 
        // Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
        $results = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        // Ejecutamos
        
         if($results)   {  

            echo json_encode($results);

         } else {
            $outPut['error']="Cero filas encontradas";
            echo("0");
        }
    } else {
        #Cambiarlo por error personalizado
        $outPut['error']=sprintf("Error SQL: %s",$bdd->errorInfo()[2]);
         echo("0");
    }
} else {
    $outPut['error']='No hay conexión';
    echo("0");
}
```

Mi clase P:

```
    int id;

    String usuario;
    String org;

    String tipo;

    String a;
    String d;

    String p;
    String r;
    String rI;
    String rF;
    String pP;
    String pA;

    String c;
    String p1;
    String p2;
    String p3;
    String p4;
    String t1;
    String t2;
    String t3;
    String t4;
    int e1;
    int e2;
    int e3;
    int e4;

    String fI;
    String fF;
    String hI;
    String hF;
    String nD;
    String dur;

String v;
String apar;
String info;

int hid, com, rprec, rpfle,nc,nl,lin,bat,bot,flec,str,ben,sil,boc,bo,cguia,sco;
    int mvl,dcs,ra,gps,bruj,map,man,vvc,arn,cuer,con,cuch,chal,flo;

    int comb,herra,rpter,rpimp;

    int crmp, tien,sac,mech,bast,cdobls,pio,horn,carb;

    int esq,rec,gven,raq,arva,habs;
```

***AsynTask para recibir el JSON***

```
class PlanAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls)
    {
        return POST(url);
    }
    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        mP= new P();

        pd = new ProgressDialog(Listado.this);
        pd.setMessage("Conectando con el servidor");
        pd.show();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
        if (result.trim().equals("0"))
        {
            Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error en la conexión", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast1.show();
        }

        else{
            //Parsear result de JSON con GSON

Log.i("JSON MODIFICAR",result);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            mP = gson.fromJson(result, P.class);
            if (pd != null)
            {
                pd.dismiss();
            }

            Intent i = new Intent(Listado.this,ModificarActividad.class);
            i.putExtra("mP",mP);
            startActivity(i);

        }

    }
```

***LOG DEL JSON***

> {"id":"2","tipo":"B","usuario":"sP","org":"","a":"\tCarretera","d":"C","p":"Z","r":"","rI":"A","rF":"Z","pP":"","pA":"","c":"","p1":"","p2":"","p3":"","p4":"","t1":null,"t2":null,"t3":"","t4":"","e1":"0","e2":"0","e3":"","e4":"","fI":"24/09/2021","fF":"24/11/2021","hI":"12:13","hF":"13:13","nD":"62","dur":"1
> horas ","v":"","apar":"","info":""}

***ERROR***

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:241)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:231)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
        at mlab.sp.Listado$PlanAsync.onPostExecute(Listado.java:1152)
        at mlab.sp.Listado$PlanAsync.onPostExecute(Listado.java:1117)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:175)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5279)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""
        at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
        at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:248)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:295)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextInt(JsonReader.java:1178)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$7.read(TypeAdapters.java:239)
```

Comment: Tu error parece indicar que hay un valor que debería ser un `double`, pero en el JSON está llegando una cadena vacía para ese valor. Para evitar eso, deberías asegurar en tu código PHP que los valores vacíos viajen con valor `0`  (cero) en el caso de los datos numéricos (dobles, enteros)  y no como cadenas vacías. Aunque hay algo que no me cuadra y es que en tu clase `P` (a la que aparentemente mapeas el JSON) no veo declarado ningún miembro del tipo `double` ¿?

Comment: Otra cosa: te aconsejo que quites todos los `echo (0);` que tienes en tu código de servidor. Ese código está escrito precisamente pensando en que podría ser usado en contexto de WebService que espera un JSON. Significa que para los casos de error, en el cliente (Android en este caso) bastaría con buscar si hay una clave `error` en la respuesta del WebService. De ese modo en ningún caso se rompe el contrato según el cual **el servidor debe responder siempre con un JSON válido**. Si tú pones esos `echo (0);` dicho contrato se rompe y no podrás determinar los casos de error en el cliente.

Comment: @A.Cedano no tengo ningún dato de tipo double, es lo que me extraña a mí por eso no sé donde puede estar el error. De hecho cambie SELECT * por SELECT campo1,...,campoN por si fuese cosa del campo date que es de tipo DATETIME

Comment: Pues el mensaje de error es bastante claro: *`Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""`* Indica que en algua parte se está intentando convertir una cadena vacía a un valor `double` ¿Podrías agregar tu clase `P` completa a la pregunta? El error podría estar ocurriendo en la clase (por ejemplo en los *setter* de la misma).

Comment: En tu clase `P` tienes variables en enteros, según tú todos tus datos son `Varchar`, ¿Por qué mezclas `int` con `Varchar`? En tu JSON e3 te devuelve: `"e3":""` Eso significa que está trayendo una cadena vacía. Entonces, repito, ¿Por qué mezclas `int` si según tú todo es `varchar`?

Comment: @A.Cedano en mi clase JAVA hay muchos int, supongo que será ese el error, que no los paso desde PHP

Comment: Muestra la clase completa, pues el mensaje de error habla claramente de un `double`. Gson usa los *setter* de la clase para mapear y puede que en alguno de ellos intentes algo con un `double`. De todos modos, como ya dije, debes cuidar que tu JSON traiga valores del tipo específico en la clase. De modo que si por ejemplo `id` es declarado como `int`  en la clase, no deberías mandarlo así en el JSON: `"id": "2"`  sino así: `"id": 2`, sin comillas, pues si va en comillas será interpretado como un String, y lo mismo para todos los demás valores. Eso aplica también para double y boolean.

Comment: he actualizado el php y estoy enviando todos los int de esta forma: `$plan->habs=$results[habs];` pero sigo recibiendo null. Plan es un objeto php que he creado puesto que para rellenar el objeto JAVA tengo que hacer dos consultas a dos tablas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como bien se ha dicho en los comentarios, había dos problemas:

- Uno es tratar en php los int como varchar, puesto que al no estar inicializados pone null o "" en vez de 0, y al parsear en JAVA da error.
- El otro error era no enviar todos los campos de la clase JAVA desde el PHP.

Dejo un poco de código con comentarios:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM p WHERE usuario = :usuario AND plan = :id";
                 if( $stmt = $bdd->prepare($sql) ) 
                 {
                    $stmt->bindParam(':usuario', $usuario);
                    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
                    $stmt -> execute(); 
                    // Especificamos el fetch mode antes de llamar a fetch()
                    $results = $stmt -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    // Ejecutamos

                     if($results)   {  

                         $p->id = $results[id]; //Al ser un int se envía así y no así: $p->id = $results["id"];

....
```

No sé sie stá bien responder así, si no es correcta esta forma lo cambio.

Gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Podrías añadir a tu respuesta el código que modificaste para que personas en el futuro, con tu mismo problema, puedan ver la respuesta completa y se orienten :)

Comment: de acuerdo, gracias por el consejo